# Directory permissions change after file upload

Tags: php, apache, laravel-4

I am not sure if to post this in SO or SF. I try it here.

I have a Laravel App running on an Apache Server.
At one part user can upload an image.

I set the folder to which the user upload to:

```
chmod 777 uploads
```

`stat uploads` returns

> Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)

Now my user can upload his image and everything works great. But when I try to upload another image I get an error that I don't have access to the folder and another

`stat uploads` returns

> Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)

Why do he permissions change?

Comment: There should never be any need to 777 anything anyway - why would a "guest" user (nobody) need write access at all? It sounds like there's an issue with the way you're attempting to (mis)use the *nix permissions model.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially this is kinda security fix of a service you run.

You better set the 775 and make the folder owner group the one of the user that runs Apache (maybe apache is run on your system by www-data:users)

in that case that would be

```
chown www-data:users uploads
```

Hope that helps.